# Redmine, SMTP & Mandrill Custom Header Template

Tags: redmine, mandrill

I'm using Redmine and have configured my configuration.yml to work with Mandrill's SMTP. Email works without doubt, but I would like to assign a template from Mandrill to it:

```
# default configuration options for all environments
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: "smtp.mandrillapp.com"
      port: 587
      domain: "example.org"
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "username"
      password: "password"
      headers["X-MC-Template"]: "templatename|main"
```

It doesn't send the header template to Mandrill, although I think it should work this way. As far as I have checked from the sourcecode of Redmine, it uses ActionMailer (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/8785/entry/trunk/app/models/mailer.rb)

Docs:
https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582117-How-to-Use-SMTP-Headers-to-Customize-Your-Messages#custom-header-reference

ActionMailer: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/headers

Anyone who is familiar with Actionmailer?

Comment: Have you tried just  X-MC-Template:"templatename|main"

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it didn't work.